# how to store files(user uploaded photos) and access it without any loss through php code in openshift

Tags: php, git, openshift

My problem is that everytime when a user uploads photos through my app in openshift it gets lost.When i try to update the code through git,I couldn't find a solution on the net.So I came here for experts advice. i would also appreciate  if anyone can point me to an article that does it for php app in openshift.

The problem is simple my user uploaded files are stored in `/user/{$_SESSION['id']}` folder that is located in repo folder. through research i found that it should be stored in `app-root/data` folder. If so how can i store user uploaded photos directly there and access it for the user who wants to view it in browser directly like `www.testing-pad4u.rhcloud.com/home.php?u={$_SESSION['name']}`.

i have no clue on how to do it please help me or point me in the right direction as i'm a total noob to Linux.

after some troubleshooting steps as told in this site `https://yuan3y.com/2014/10/setting-up-an-upload-folder-in-openshift/` i modified the code for my own purposes and here is the code:

```
`#!/bin/bash
# This deploy hook gets executed after dependencies are resolved and the
# build hook has been run but before the application has been started back
# up again.  This script gets executed directly, so it could be python, php,
# ruby, etc.
# This script will create a permanent storage folder on openshift
# put this in .openshift/action_hooks/build

echo ".............pre_build............creating symlinks.................";
if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/user" ]; then
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/user
echo "directory user made.";
if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/group" ]; then
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/group
    echo "directory group made.";

ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/user $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/user
ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/upload/group $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/group
echo ".................creating symlinks completed........................";

##source: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/one-newbie-question`
```

and the error i get is as follows:
`line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 2)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'build'`

Comment: show us what you had tried yet..?

Comment: @pranavm.s i tried only hot_deploy so far. Because i didnt want to ruin things with some thing that i dont understand.

Comment: Use a symlink to the Openshift data folder.

Comment: yes i followed the instructions given on `https://yuan3y.com/2014/10/setting-up-an-upload-folder-in-openshift/` but i get an error dont know why @fatfantasma

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: here is the error `line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 2)' `and i will update the code i used above @fatfantasma

Comment: Is the execution bit set on the "build" action hook file?

Comment: i think so??? @fatfantasma dont even know how to check that

Comment: Probably not: )  ssh Into your app and do a  "ls  -a"  in the directory of the build action hook and see if the execution bit is set on the file.  Google for Linux/unix execution  bit for more info. See my answer if not.

Answer (score 0):

Set execution bit on your "build" action hook file.

Using Git Bash

```
git update-index --chmod=+x <your_file>
```

Then commit and push.

Here is my action hook as an example.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ".................Starting 'post_deploy' Action Hook..................................."
echo ".................attempting 'uploads' setting up symlink........................"
echo "................................................................................"
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/thp/static
ln -s $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/uploads uploads
echo ".................creating 'uploads' completed........................"
echo "................................................................................"
```

Comment: Remotely. Updating your git file like I showed you. If you don't,  it will keep clearing everytime  you push a new update.

Comment: Did the execution bit get set?  SSh or WinSCP into your app and check it.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You will need to change the path to your own path.

Comment: i think the file is set but im still getting the above error bro

Comment: Do you think or know?  Makes a big difference ; )  show us your file status bird.

Comment: @fatfantasmo i have added a picture for reference bro :)

Comment: Hmm.  I'm on iPhone now.  Can only see so much.  What's on line 22?

Comment: Ssh into app and try to run your build action hook by yourself.  Does it work?

Comment: @fatfantasmo the build was successful after i tweaked your bash script but there was no user or group folders created in the `data/uploads` folder any idea where im going wrong. i'll paste the tweaked code above please review and advice

Comment: I'm not a Bash script guy.  I'm guessing your if/thens are failing for some reason.  Just ssh to your app and make the directories manually for now.

Comment: @fatfantasmo will that be sufficient to make it a persistent one for user uploaded files ??

Comment: It will be fine.  The Openshift data directory is persistent.

Comment: Looking at your original bash script I see you had an apostrophe at the beginning and end of the file.  I'm guessing that was your original error.

Comment: ah i see now, but still if i upload a photo through the app and use git to make changes afterwards the uploaded file gets lost any advice on that bro??? @fatfantasmo

Comment: The file is not placed in the Openshift data directory.  Upload a file and make sure it's there. Pushes always clear out your repo.  The data directory is persistent.